# Distinguish forwarding traffic and locally originated traffic in Linux network driver

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any information in the `struct skbuff` to distinguish between the forwarding traffic (bridge forwarding and ip forwarding) and locally originated traffic? We want to treat these two kinds of traffic differently in the network driver because the forwarding traffic do not require cache invalidation on the whole packet size.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can try to follow the life cycle of a receiving packet by looking at all calls from this function  `ip_rcv_finish` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c?v=3.3#L317).

The struct `struct sk_buff` contain a pointer to the destination entry :

```
struct  dst_entry   *dst;
```

which contain a function pointer :

```
int (*input)(struct sk_buff*);
```

to call for the input packet, in the case of local packet the kernel call `ip_local_deliver` function and for the forwarding packet it calls `ip_forward` function.

I think that you can, check like this for local and forwarded packets:

**- Local :**

```
/*  struct sk_buff *skb : Entry packet */
if (((struct rtable *)skb->dst)->rt_type == RTN_LOCAL)
{
    /* This packet is to consume locally */
}
```

**- Forward :**

```
if (((struct rtable *)skb->dst)->rt_type == RTN_UNICAST)
{
    /* This packet will be forwarded */
}
```

Comment: Thank @TOC a lot for your answer! With your hint, we can mark the forwarding packet inside `ip_forward` (for IP forwarding) and `br_handle_frame_finish` (for bridge forwarding)

Comment: @toc's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113254/4172145) is awesome. For further reading on the the path a packet takes from userspace to kernel and back, see Ashwin Chimata's excellent paper [here](http://www.hsnlab.hu/twiki/pub/Targyak/Mar11Cikkek/Network_stack.pdf)